# why ESP32 ssl connect fails

Tags: c++, ssl, esp32

I am using the WiFiSecureClient example n arduino studio. I first ran the example on my ESP 32 cam with the website howsmyssl and it works.

Then I created and hosted my own nodejs app on a domain and generated a letsencrypt certificate for it so all requests are directed to ssl.

I than exported the certificate from google chrome and changed the howsmyssl certificate to my own site's certificate.

The problem is that it does not connect and I get the message connection failed in the serial monitor.

Here is my code,
Essentially its the same code as in the example but for some reason the server is not connecting. Would appreciate any advise on how to debug/correct this.:

```
/*
  Wifi secure connection example for ESP32
  Running on TLS 1.2 using mbedTLS
  Suporting the following chipersuites:
  "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM","TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_PSK_DHE_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM","TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_PSK_DHE_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8","TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8","TLS_PSK_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA","TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"]
  2017 - Evandro Copercini - Apache 2.0 License.
*/

#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

const char* ssid     = "myap";     // your network SSID (name of wifi network)
const char* password = "mypass"; // your network password

const char*  server = "growgreen.life";  // Server URL

// www.howsmyssl.com root certificate authority, to verify the server
// change it to your server root CA
// SHA1 fingerprint is broken now!

const char* test_root_ca= \
     "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
     "MIIFNTCCBB2gAwIBAgISA923aMjf7A21sbQ131UqqWdiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA\n" \
     "MDIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MQswCQYDVQQD\n" \
     "EwJSMzAeFw0yMTA3MTIwNTI3MzJaFw0yMTEwMTAwNTI3MzFaMBkxFzAVBgNVBAMT\n" \
     "Dmdyb3dncmVlbi5saWZlMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA\n" \
     "ocNfRneLCVSsl6ZOHaQQ9wQqtEjfuX/rn625xP/VWmikNlPkFrhP6Hm5HbXkpMSB\n" \
     "+vGX3ms6tjoIWgipeusHo3shz+RsqVDGpfdxsNbKApHL8JxaIWjYaAlJDfw7SPOP\n" \
     "lv+wqJXR7it83l5DuPrgu2jxbmDgrWdWbbXJYTs2kLbMANIMplYgHua3wGSovpGt\n" \
     "PcK8LeohsEJk1cntqtcaznJFxA6s54hKtv/L03WgkNUlONX2BWrwv/OBsGkCN123\n" \
     "5JmZ7iyocjaH6x5ixp7ULAtPKpsI5OQ+2zcgQIBRxLW3Tv4rBF0p7JAXlJHjuAqH\n" \
     "52LW8pySppIeLsR+FM6O+wIDAQABo4ICXDCCAlgwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0G\n" \
     "A1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB0GA1Ud\n" \
     "DgQWBBT9KWvWs7GmeyfSgnS/eWMmku/5sTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQULrMXt1hWy65Q\n" \
     "CUDmH6+dixTCxjBVBggrBgEFBQcBAQRJMEcwIQYIKwYBBQUHMAGGFWh0dHA6Ly9y\n" \
     "My5vLmxlbmNyLm9yZzAiBggrBgEFBQcwAoYWaHR0cDovL3IzLmkubGVuY3Iub3Jn\n" \
     "LzAtBgNVHREEJjAkgg5ncm93Z3JlZW4ubGlmZYISd3d3Lmdyb3dncmVlbi5saWZl\n" \
     "MEwGA1UdIARFMEMwCAYGZ4EMAQIBMDcGCysGAQQBgt8TAQEBMCgwJgYIKwYBBQUH\n" \
     "AgEWGmh0dHA6Ly9jcHMubGV0c2VuY3J5cHQub3JnMIIBAwYKKwYBBAHWeQIEAgSB\n" \
     "9ASB8QDvAHUARJRlLrDuzq/EQAfYqP4owNrmgr7YyzG1P9MzlrW2gagAAAF6mWY+\n" \
     "9QAABAMARjBEAiAhHEeGYKpneNn2/GnYzvgXtflgAap8sRpzzu5h123/YwIgQ0jb\n" \
     "xgImVVDW2usWjENjmgnIUYk4W03p8AdyuKchtgsAdgD2XJQv0XcwIhRUGAgwlFaO\n" \
     "400TGTO/3wwvIAvMTvFk4wAAAXqZZj7vAAAEAwBHMEUCIQCIMPL8yUXTwl9dFvsT\n" \
     "Fy+WKRlPEImFQiiNYkyAXUmFLgIgJlTi2679ZvYIlLUq4wS/CXJHsYIzFI6qILfu\n" \
     "V+7d0BIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAKOXihmS7Byw5Q4cYXbVmqFZqLuXJod5\n" \
     "1GZYIfsfmeH6By93Hjlqcm58L5/DLNA6Yfqnu9mmWrAPd0MYz7PGvlxzDbN/ggGK\n" \
     "fD0PjwuREln5vgHXKOysYCJ7ho58g9DN4mkS2679FD2WiYXMpntYQtQP24noIaw1\n" \
     "DmeS8h6xXQcDIEVVWki9Rst/S3dvI/LQUaQ0UCe8EeDbrYgKj9eMZH32ENqcb5NE\n" \
     "LikNcXQpl/cgAbb3xczFAMBL7Vo8QxAM9bMiyfp58zh0bcFJkH9bNDEQ9uQdkHTP\n" \
     "nukplj5DC7V5+FHPyBvTdUCRTPKf9cjHEvbCLCMicCMbeCjZ69cYhSo=\n" \
     "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";


// You can use x.509 client certificates if you want
//const char* test_client_key = "";   //to verify the client
//const char* test_client_cert = "";  //to verify the client


WiFiClientSecure client;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    // wait 1 second for re-trying
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  client.setCACert(test_root_ca);
  //client.setCertificate(test_client_key); // for client verification
  //client.setPrivateKey(test_client_cert);  // for client verification

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  if (!client.connect(server, 443))
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
  else {
    Serial.println("Connected to server!");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET https://growgreen.life");
    client.println("Host: growgreen.life");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    while (client.connected()) {
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
      if (line == "\r") {
        Serial.println("headers received");
        break;
      }
    }
    // if there are incoming bytes available
    // from the server, read them and print them:
    while (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.write(c);
    }

    client.stop();
  }
}

void loop() {
  // do nothing
}
```

I changed the leaf certificate with the root certificate and now I am able to connect to the server. But for some reason I am getting the bad request 400 response...following is the response in the serial monitor:

```
Starting connection to server...
Connected to server!
headers received
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the output of your program? Try increasing logging verbosity of ESP IDF to get more information out of it. You are also passing your site's leaf certificate in place of a CA certificate - I'd assume this should work but I'd also try one of the real CA certificates in your chain - apparently in the output of `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect growgreen.life:443` it's something like this: `s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1`.

Comment: Thanks Tarmo...I changed the leaf certificate to the root certificate and am now able to connect...I have also received headers from the site which is confusing, I am getting a bad request 400 page, where as if I open my site in the browser with growgreen.life I get my original hello world page. Any advise...I have editind my original question with the response I have recieved.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the right way to request a page in http: `client.println("GET https://growgreen.life");`. The GET request in HTTP v1 is something like `GET /index.html`

Comment: But the same format is being used in the example and it runs fine on the howsmyssl.com...the get request is being sent like this: GET https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check HTTP/1.0

instead of calling a certain html page, a call to a route is being made which returns a json dataset.

Comment: Nevertheless your HTTP request is faulty, that's literally what the error message is telling you. Note that howsmyssl.com and your site run different web servers. Try for example `GET /index.html`. Note that testing your HTTP requests by writing HTTP client code for your embedded device is the slowest possible way of debugging this. Open a raw TLS connection, try out the commands - you get immediate feedback. E.g. `openssl s_client -connect growgreen.life:443`

Comment: You are right...I am running a different server. Can you point me to some example code? Would help a lot. I have changed the code at the web server end, my nodejs app now returns a json response object containing dummy data for now. 

The purpose is to send and receive data from the web server to the ESP32 cam.

Comment: I don't have example code. You just need to send a correct HTTP GET request. It's rather simple to google for examples of HTTP requests and then try them out by copying and pasting text into an established TLS pipe. If your JSON comes back, you've got it.

Comment: What @Tarmo told you is correct. Your HTTP request is malformed. The `GET` line shouldn't include `https://` or the domain name. Look at the example you provided that works and you'll see the difference. But why even implement the HTTP protocol yourself? There's a good `HTTPClient` implementation in the [ESP32 Arduino Core](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/HTTPClient). Use it and you won't have these problems.

Comment: Had a similar issue. In case it's related I wanted to link here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686127/freertos-arduino-httpclient-gets-esp-sha-failed-to-allocate-buf-memory-error

Answer (score -1):

```
const char* host="Your host server" ;

const int httpsPort = 443;

//use below inside the function u want to connect with server

WiFiClientSecure client;
client.setInsecure();

HTTPClient http;

client.connect(host, httpsPort);

http.begin(client, host);

String payload;

if (http.GET() == HTTP_CODE_OK)    

        payload = http.getString();
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thank you for your reply...but my original post states that there no issues with the original example when I run it aginst howsmyssl.com, the problem is when I change the certificate accordingly for my own site. Otherwise the get request and server connection work fine. So could you help me understand what am I doing wrong with the certificate?

Comment: The `client.setInsecure();` call simply disabled the certificate checking.  This isn't really a fix.