# FreeRTOS Arduino HTTPClient gets "esp-sha: Failed to allocate buf memory" error

Tags: freertos, arduino-esp32

I was getting this error intermittently using an ESP32 to access an SSL web api using the Arduino `HTTPClient` and `WifiClientSecure`. I spent weeks through trial and error trying to solve this and finally got the solution. I will post below. I wanted to share because I could not find the solution posted anywhere already.

Note, this also caused these error at random times:

- connection refused
- DNS failure

Code looks like this:

```
WiFiClientSecure apiClient;
apiClient.setCACert(apiRootCACertificate); // or use aviationweatherClient.setInsecure();
apiClient.setHandshakeTimeout(CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT);

HTTPClient http;
http.setTimeout(HTTP_TIMEOUT);
http.setConnectTimeout(HTTP_TIMEOUT);
http.useHTTP10(true);
http.setReuse(false);
http.setFollowRedirects(HTTPC_STRICT_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS);

char * host = "www.someapi.com";  
int port = 443;
char * apiUri = "/functionname"
bool useSSL = true;

http.begin(apiClient, host, port, apiUri, useSSL);

int httpCode = http.GET();
if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK)
{
    DynamicJsonDocument jsonDoc(8000);
    DeserializationError e = deserializeJson(jsonDoc, http.getStream());
}

http.end();
aviationweatherClient.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error was I was allocating too much stack space to all the FreeRTOS tasks, and there wasn't space for the HTTPClient to allocate buffer space. I tuned down the tasks to only use the minimum stack sizes and the issue resolved.

For example:

```
#define RTOS_UPDATE_TIME_STACK_SIZE 3500 // usage logged at 2924
xTaskCreate(RTOSTasks::timeCallback, "tUpdateTime", RTOS_UPDATE_TIME_STACK_SIZE, (void *)0, RTOS_UPDATE_TIME_PRIORITY, &tUpdateTimeHandle);
```

And I used this method to get the most used stack size to determine what was needed:

```
void RTOSTasks::logStackUsage(time_t *lastRun, const char *tag)
{
    time_t currentRun = TimeHelpers::Now();

    if (DEBUG_SHOW_RTOS_MEMORY_USAGE == 1)
    {
        // only show every 10 seconds
        if (currentRun > (*lastRun) + RTOS_MEMORY_SAMPLE_INTERVAL)
        {
            auto stack = uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL);

            if (stack < RTOS_LOW_STACK_THRESHOLD || stack > RTOS_HIGH_STACK_THRESHOLD)
                ESP_LOGW(tag, "remaining stack (high watermark): %d", stack);

            *lastRun = currentRun;
        }
    }
}
```